# posting input tag in hebrew

Tags: html, jsp, encoding, hebrew

I am sending in the fileName a hebrew word "הי" 
and it return "??"

really need help on this,
thanks for the helpers!

for encoding I added the top of this html lines :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1255"
    pageEncoding="windows-1255"%>
```

JSP:

```
<form name='DMform' id='DMform' style="height: 226px; " method="Post" >
<center>
<h2 id="titleID">title </h2>


<input type="button" value="button1" style="width: 116px; " onclick="setTextOnFile()">
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="text" name="filePath" id="filePath" style="width: 258px;" value="<%if(filePath!=null){
                out.println(filePath[0].trim());
            }%>" >

</br></br>

<input type="text" name="fileName" id="fileName" style="width: 258px;" value="<%if(fileName!=null){
                out.println(fileName[0].trim());
            }%>" >
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<label>: שם המסמך </label>
</br></br>

<input type="button" value="send" onclick="checkData();" <%if(filePath!=null){
                if(filePath[0].trim()!=""){ out.println(" disabled ");}
            }%> >
</br></br>


<input type="button" value="איפוס הטופס" onClick="window.location=window.location.href ;">

</center>
</form>
```

Java script that past:

```
function checkData(){
document['DMform'].submit();
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you use `windows-1255` and not the more general (and Java native) `UTF-8`?

Comment: Becouse the web page should work with hebrew windows, and it's for a close network, do u think it's the problem?

Comment: I tried to replace it to UTF-8 and it now : "××"